# Error in reading Postgres log by pgfouine.php

Tags: bash, postgresql, logging

I have Postgres configuration with LOGFILE defined in the bash script `/etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql` by the option -l ${LOGFILE}

Log gives the following output :

> 2013-06-07 11:28:18 EDT rentgrowLOG:  statement: select count(*) from
>   (select * from results limit 1) test
>   2013-06-07 11:28:18 EDT
>   rentgrowLOG:  duration: 0.333 ms

This output is not readable by pgfouine.php – the error is:
 “pgFouine did not find any valid PostgreSQL log line in your log file:”

I found also that my changes in postgresql.conf do not affect the output at all.

How prepare a Postgres log file readable by pgfouine.php?

Comment: What's your `log_line_prefix` in `postgresql.conf` and what are the options passed to pgFouine?

Comment: log_line_prefix = '%t [%p]: [%l-1] '
C:\pgf>\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.exe pgfouine.php -file postgresql-2013-06-07_182652.log -logtype stderr
I  do not see that changing the options in the config files changes the output.  I could not install php on Linux, so I am using windows

Answer (score 1):

> I found also that my changes in postgresql.conf do not affect the
>   output at all.

That's probably the source of the problem. Your `log_line_prefix` is being ignored. Otherwise, with the prefix set to `'%t [%p]: [%l-1] '` as recommended by pgFouine, the log entries would look like this:

```
2013-06-13 16:38:18 CEST [6203]: [2-1] LOG:  duration: 0.169 ms  statement: select 1;
```

As to the question: why are the changes to `postgresql.conf` being ignored? Some typical reasons would be:

1. Not reloading it after the change, by sending `SIGHUP` to the postmaster, either directly or through the `pg_ctl` or `service` commands.
2. Editing the wrong file. See: [Where are my postgres *.conf files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602450/where-are-my-postgres-conf-files)